# Using roslibjs and one simple action server Errors

Tags: ros, action, rosbridge, rosbridge-server, roslibjs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, using `roslibjs` to connect with `rosbridge`, with the objective of sending a goal to a simple action server, I am getting this error:

```
[INFO] [WallTime: 1423829560.345222] Client connected.  1 clients total.
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1423829560.496586] [Client 0] [id: advertise:/control/goal:1] advertise: Unable to load the manifest for package gamma. Caused by: gamma
[INFO] [WallTime: 1423829560.770795] [Client 0] Subscribed to /control/status
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1423829560.780198] [Client 0] [id: subscribe:/control/feedback:4] subscribe: Unable to load the manifest for package gamma. Caused by: gamma
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1423829560.790271] [Client 0] [id: subscribe:/control/result:5] subscribe: Unable to load the manifest for package gamma. Caused by: gamma
```

I think that the `package.xml` file is missing but i don't know what is the specific content of this file for this case (to specify the goal, result and feedback).

So where can I place the package and what does it contain?

Maybe its related to one file error, i guided my self by the tutorial and the webpage says `error at the back end`, maybe I am doing something wrong, i paste my file here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title> First button </title>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.robotwebtools.org/EventEmitter2/current/eventemitter2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.robotwebtools.org/roslibjs/current/roslib.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" type="text/javascript">

  //connect to ROS
  var ros = new ROSLIB.Ros({ url: 'ws://localhost:9090' });

  //emit the error on the backend if exist
  ros.on('error', function(error) {
      document.getElementById('connecting').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('connected').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('closed').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('error').style.display = 'inline';
    console.log(error);
  });

  //Connection made
  ros.on('connection', function() {
    console.log('Connection made');
      document.getElementById('connecting').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('connected').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('closed').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('error').style.display = 'inline';
  });
  
  //Connection closed
  ros.on('close', function() {
    console.log('Connection closed');
      document.getElementById('connecting').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('connected').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('closed').style.display = 'none';
  });

  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  //Action Client
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  // Conect to the server on charge of the mobile control of the turtlebot
  var controlServer = new ROSLIB.ActionClient({
    ros : ros,
    serverName: '/control',
    actionName: 'gamma/ControlAction'
  });  

  //Created function to move foward the turtlebot
  function forward() {
    //Create the variable that will be associated to the goal
    var twist = new ROSLIB.Message ({
      linear : {
        x : 0.1, 
        y : 0.0, 
        z : 0.0 
      },
      angular : { 
        x : 0.0, 
        y : 0.0, 
        z : 0.0
      } 
    }); 

    //Create the goal
    var goal = new ROSLIB.Goal({
      actionClient : controlServer,
      goalMessage : twist 
    });

    //Send the goal to the server to execute the callbacks
    goal.send();
    console.log("Goal sent forward");
    return true;
  }
  </script>

</head>

<body>

  <div id="statusIndicator">
    <p id="connecting">
      Connecting to rosbridge...
    </p>
    <p id="connected" style="color:#00D600; display:none">
      Connected
    </p>
    <p id="error" style="color:#FF0000; display:none">
      Error in the backend!
    </p>
    <p id="closed" style="display:none">
      Connection closed.
    </p>
  </div>

  <div> <button id="forward" type="action" onclick="forward()">Forward</button> </div>
</body>

</html>
```

What could be the problem at the back end?
Thanks beforehand!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203087/using-roslibjs-and-one-simple-action-server-errors/) by [pexison](https://answers.ros.org/users/21144/pexison/) on ROS Answers with karma: 82 on 2015-02-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem was with this line of code:

```
  var controlServer = new ROSLIB.ActionClient({
    ros : ros,
    serverName: '/control',
    actionName: 'gamma/ControlAction'  <-----------
  });
```

Changed `actionName` to the right location of the `.action` file solved the problem.

---

Originally posted by [pexison](https://answers.ros.org/users/21144/pexison/) with karma: 82 on 2015-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0